# Add parameter on UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I would like to ask on how to add a parameter on the UITapGestureRecognizer on my UILabel. So far this is what I got:

```
self.feedSource.text = source_link
                    self.feedSource.userInteractionEnabled = true
                    let feedSourceTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("openLinkFromFeedSource"))
                    self.feedSource.addGestureRecognizer(feedSourceTapGesture)


func openLinkFromFeedSource() {
        print("tapped")
    }
```

What I want to achieve is when I tapped the label, from openLinkFromFeedSource I can get the value of the self.feedSource.text

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should get this from tap gesture action like this:

```
func didTapOnView(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let label = tap.view
    // do with that label
}
```

Comment: You should mention that the `action` parameter needs to be updated to reflect the addition of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
self.feedSource.userInteractionEnabled = true
let feedSourceTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("openLinkFromFeedSource:"))
self.feedSource.addGestureRecognizer(feedSourceTapGesture)


func openLinkFromFeedSource(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  let label = sender.view

    print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: Why did someone down vote this answer? It's much better than the other answer.